# Expo: Cannot resolve entry file: The `main` field defined in your `package.json` points to a non-existent path

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, monorepo

I am working with the default typescript template generated from the command line `npx create-expo-app -t expo-template-blank-typescript` and I get this error when I try to start the project.

The main reason I think, is because I am working in a monorepo.

The entry point in package.json points to `"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"` but in a monorepo, the expo module is only present in the parent `node_modules` folder.

### What I have tried

I have tried setting up the entry point in app.json to: `./src/App.tsx`, `./dist/App.js` with no success

When I change the main field of package.json to `../../node_modules/expo/AppEntry.ts` I got this error:

**Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11)**

### My setup

I am working with turborepo. My folder structure look like

```
├── app
│   ├──project1
│   │  ├── package.json
│   │  ├── App.tsx
│   │  ├── app.json
│   │  └── tsconfig.json
│   └──node_modules
└── node_modules
    └── expo
        └── AppEntry.js
```

---

Is there a clean way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/

You need to override metro config:

> There are three main changes we need to:
>
> - Make sure Metro is watching the full monorepo, not just apps/cool-app.
> - Tell Metro where it can resolve packages. They might be installed in apps/cool-app/node_modules or node_modules.
> - Force Metro to only resolve (sub)packages from the nodeModulesPaths.
>
> We can configure this by creating a metro.config.js with the following content:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

// Find the project and workspace directories
const projectRoot = __dirname;
// This can be replaced with `find-yarn-workspace-root`
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, '../..');

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

// 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
// 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages and in what order
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
];
// 3. Force Metro to resolve (sub)dependencies only from the `nodeModulesPaths`
config.resolver.disableHierarchicalLookup = true;

module.exports = config;
```

**AND**

Change the default entry point in `index.js`

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: can you share you package.json and the index.js/ts file?

Comment: @vlio20 I am not sure it will help, my package.json has nothing special and there is no index file in the root of the repo. The relevant configs here are metro.config.js and index.js in the expo app. My files are exactly like in the doc above.

Comment: Did you use index.js ot index.ts?
So the value was just: "main": "index.js"  ?

I am keep getting the following error:
Error: Cannot resolve entry file: The `main` field defined in your `package.json` points to a non-existent path.

Comment: Didi you change anything in the `metro.config.js` file?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the doc => https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/#modify-the-metro-config